# AWS S3 uploading an object which is publicly readable

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the AWS v2 java SDK.
I am trying to upload an object to my bucket. I want the object to be publicly readable.

What I have done is as follows:

```
     PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequest =S3Presigner.create()
                .presignPutObject(z -> z.signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                    .putObjectRequest(
                                por -> por.bucket("MYBUCKET")
                                    .key("MYOBJECTKEY")
                                    .acl(ObjectCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ)));
   URL url = presignedRequest.url();
```

I then use this URL to upload a file. I am getting a 403 response when I do this.

If I remove the line adding the acl, then the upload works.

If I change the ACL to PRIVATE, that too fails.

From my aws console, I can make an object public, so I dont think that it is a bucket policy problem.

How can this be fixed? I want to upload an object to a bucket and make it publicly readable

After some more debugging from my end, it looks to be a problem with the way the URL is being built.
This is part of the URL when I dont add an ACL

```
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=120
```

And this is the similar part of the URL with an ACL

```
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&X-Amz-Expires=120
```

It looks like the URL building gets borked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pre-signed URL is only granting access if the ACL is public, you'll probably need to add a `x-amz-acl=public-read` header to satisfy the constraint.

See: [PutObjectAcl - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObjectAcl.html)

Comment: This works. I am curious to know how though. For example, when I create the URL with an ACL "public read" and use the URL with the header "authenticated-read", the PUT request is forbidden, which is expected behaviour. But I cant understand, how S3 knows to reject this, since the creation time acl, doesnt appear in the URL

Comment: The signature for the pre-signed URL is based on a hash of the header. If the header doesn't match, then the request is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, the code snippet to  upload the object while setting the public read header is as follows

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
connection.setRequestProperty("x-amz-acl", "public-read");
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write("This text uploaded as an object via presigned URL.");  
out.close();
```

The key part is

```
connection.setRequestProperty("x-amz-acl", "public-read");
```